# Delegating to list initialized constructor, empty fields

Tags: c++

So I have the following, simple setup.

.hpp

```
class User {
std::string firstName;
std::string lastName;
std::string email;
std::string phoneNr;

public:
    User(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string email);
    User(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string email,
        std::string phoneNr);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o, User &u);
};
```

.cpp

```
   User::User(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string email)
    :firstName(fName),lastName(lName),email(email){
}


//Works
User::User(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string email,
    std::string phoneNr)
    :firstName(fName), lastName(lName),email(email),phoneNr(phoneNr){
}

//Does not work
User::User(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string email,
    std::string phoneNr){
    User(fName,lName,email,phoneNr);
    this->phoneNr = phoneNr;
}


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &a, User &b){
    a<<b.firstName<<" "<<b.lastName<<std::endl;
    a<<b.email<<std::endl;
    a<<b.phoneNr<<std::endl;
}
```

Now, why is it that the implementation of the second constructor, where I delegate to the first constructor, leaves the fields empty? This makes little sense to me, the first constructor is called (verified by printouts) but it doesn't initialize anything.

Does this mean I am forced to, in c++, to use list initialization on all constructors if they have to delegate to a list initialized constructor?

Comment: That's not the syntax for [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor). Your compiler should also warn you about that missing return statement in `operator<<`.

Comment: I should unlearn java to learn C++ it seems. It felt "natural" for me to be able to delegate to a constructor using User(...) but it just creates a tmp that does nothing? Thanks for the lesson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegation should happen in the member initializer list. You are simply creating a `User` temporary. Here's the fixed syntax:

```
User::User(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string email,
    std::string phoneNr) : 
    User(fName,lName,email)
{
    this->phoneNr = phoneNr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegate constructor should be:

```
User::User(std::string fName, std::string lName, std::string email, std::string phoneNr) : User(fName, lName, email, phoneNr)
{
    this->phoneNr = phoneNr;
}
```

BTW, in your case your may use only one constructor with default parameter

```
User::User(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string email, std::string phoneNr = "") :
    firstName(fName), lastName(lName), email(email), phoneNr(phoneNr)
```